# FreeRTOS stuck at prvCheckTasksWaitingTermination

Tags: delay, stm32, freertos

I'm working with a Nucleo-STm32F767 and I had generated the code with CubeMX including FreeRTOS 9.

My code has 5 task and each task has a loop, where the task is suspended on each iteration.

```
  while( 1 )
  {   
    //Do something

    osDelay(TASK_MAIN_DELAY_MS);
  }
```

At this point my system works well.

Now I added a task that handle the communication with an SPI network controller. The network controller has it own middleware written in C.

Now every time I try to suspend a task (with osDelay) my code is stucked into **prvCheckTasksWaitingTermination** and my system is blocked forever.

```
static void prvCheckTasksWaitingTermination( void )
{

    /** THIS FUNCTION IS CALLED FROM THE RTOS IDLE TASK **/

    #if ( INCLUDE_vTaskDelete == 1 )
    {
        BaseType_t xListIsEmpty;

        /* ucTasksDeleted is used to prevent vTaskSuspendAll() being called
        too often in the idle task. */
        while( uxDeletedTasksWaitingCleanUp > ( UBaseType_t ) 0U )
        {
            vTaskSuspendAll();
            {
                xListIsEmpty = listLIST_IS_EMPTY( &xTasksWaitingTermination );
            }
            ( void ) xTaskResumeAll();

            if( xListIsEmpty == pdFALSE )
            {
                TCB_t *pxTCB;

                taskENTER_CRITICAL();
                {
                    pxTCB = ( TCB_t * ) listGET_OWNER_OF_HEAD_ENTRY( ( &xTasksWaitingTermination ) );
                    ( void ) uxListRemove( &( pxTCB->xStateListItem ) );
                    --uxCurrentNumberOfTasks;
                    --uxDeletedTasksWaitingCleanUp;
                }
                taskEXIT_CRITICAL();

                prvDeleteTCB( pxTCB );
            }
            else
            {
                mtCOVERAGE_TEST_MARKER();
            }
        }
    }
    #endif /* INCLUDE_vTaskDelete */
```

In particular, the execution is stopped here: while( uxDeletedTasksWaitingCleanUp > ( UBaseType_t ) 0U ) becuase **uxDeletedTasksWaitingCleanUp** is equal to 0.

I don't know how to resolve this issue :(

Anybody can help me?

Thanks and best regards,
Federico

Comment: It is usually caused by the stack overflow or wrong interrupt priorities.

Answer (score 0):

prvCheckTaskWaitingTermination is just part of the idle task.  Unless you are running tickless operation it will just keep executing as long as no higher priority tasks are able to run.  In your case I'm going to guess that the SPI driver is doing something that stops or masks the tick interrupt so time doesn't change, so delays never end.  Just a guess though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help your issue, but I was running into this same problem and was able to get past it.

In my freertos.cpp file, I had several tasks executing in succession one after another. However, the second task was being executed but would fail each time because the peripheral it was trying to use was not working properly. It seems that since I did not have a catch for this, it was having trouble switching from the task.

Once I fixed the peripheral (in my case a cellular modem that was trying to connect to an unreachable server), the program executed properly and did not get stuck in this **prvCheckTasksWaitingTermination** function.

So, in your case, perhaps this indicates an issue with your SPI configuration that needs attention.

I hope this helps.